# Symfony 3 - Data Transformer

Tags: php, symfony

Hello guys i've been stuck for the past week on a Data Transformer.

The goal of it is to transform a TextType in a Entity (Departement)
because i can do it by a EntityType.

I have read the whole documentation about it on the Symfony Doc but the error is always the same.

The error is :

Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to ExellBundle\Form\Type\SearchType::__construct() must be an instance of ExellBundle\Form\DataTransfomer\DepartementTransformer, none given, called in /Users/maxime/Documents/www/exellapp/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php on line 92 and defined

**DepartementTransformer.php**

```
<?php

  namespace ExellBundle\Form\DataTransfomer;

  use ExellBundle\Entity\Departement;
  use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
  use Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\TransformationFailedException;


 class DepartementTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{

private $em;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->em = $em;
}

/**
 * @param Departement|null $departement
 * @return string
 */
public function transform($departement)
{
    // TODO: Implement transform() method.
    if(null == $departement)
    {
        return '';
    }
    return $departement->getId();
}


/**
 * @param string $departementNumber
 * @return Departement|null
 * @throws TransformationFailedException if object (departement) is not found
 */
public function reverseTransform($departementNumber)
{
    // TODO: Implement reverseTransform() method.
    if(!$departementNumber)
    {
        return;
    }
    $departement  = $this->em->getRepository('ExellBundle:Departement')->find($departementNumber);

    if(null === $departement)
    {
        throw  new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
            'Le departement %s n\'existe pas ! ',
            $departementNumber
        ));
    }

    return $departement;
}

}
```

**SearchType.php**

```
<?php

namespace ExellBundle\Form\Type;

use ExellBundle\Form\DataTransfomer\DepartementTransformer;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use ExellBundle\Entity\Bien;

class SearchType extends AbstractType
{


private $transformer;

public function __construct(DepartementTransformer $transformer)
{
    $this->transformer = $transformer;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('typeInvest',EntityType::class,array(
        'placeholder' => 'Veuillez choisir',
        'label' => 'Type d\'investistement',
        'class' => 'ExellBundle\Entity\TypeInvest',
        'choice_label' => 'libelle',
        'expanded' => false,
        'multiple' => false,
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'form-inline',
            'required' => true,
        ]
    ))
    /*->add('departement',EntityType::class,array(
        'placeholder' => 'Veuillez renseigner le Département',
        'class' => 'ExellBundle\Entity\Departement',
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'form-inline',
            'required' => true,
        ],
    ));*/

    ->add('departement',TextType::class,array(
        'invalid_message' => ' Cela n\'est pas un numéro de département valide',
    ));

    $builder->get('departement')->addModelTransformer($this->transformer);

}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Bien::class,
    ));
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'exellbundle_bien';
}

}
```

Comment: How are you using the SearchType? Initially, it looks like you're not passing the DepartementTransformer into the SearchType class, which is exactly what the error message is saying.

Comment: It also looks like you're missing the essential logic for auto-complete from this. A DataTransformer wouldn't typically be used for that; to avoid confusion, I suggest editing your question to remove that part.

Comment: You need to [register your form as a service](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/create_custom_field_type.html#form-field-service) to get the transformer injected.  Newer versions of Symfony (3.3 I think) can do this more or less automatically under some cases but I suspect you have an older version.

Comment: @SteveHill The SearchType is here to search some Entities in database !

Comment: @Cerad I am using Symfony 3.4.4, But i'll try this one !

Comment: Make sure you set the doc version (upper right corner) to 3.4.  I gave you 2.8 just as a guess.

Comment: @Cerad Thank you it's working now !